# Dimension types not allowed (at 'showtype' with value 'mm')

Tags: android, attr, typedarray

I've made a custom controller to check how android works with attributes, so to do that I also created a file named attrs.xml and set it like below

attrs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="durationTextView">
        <attr name="showtype" format="enum">
            <enum name="hhmmss" value="0"  />
            <enum name="hhmm" value="1" />
            <enum name="mm" value="2" />
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

---

activity.xml

```
<com.example.mustafaguven.widgets.DurationTextView
    android:id="@+id/lblDuration"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    custom:showtype="mm"
    />
```

What I'm gonna ask is that why I'm getting an error like I shared as title if I set showtype as "mm". Android has some problems specifically with the name "mm", and it's really weird because if I changed "mm" with another name, there is no any error. It works perfectly.

I'm just curious about what makes it believe its an error. please try it and see it yourself.

Comment: mm means  0millimeter ,it's a dimension.

Comment: so do you think its the reason?

Comment: why don't you try to use px instead of mm?

Comment: I've been using mm for "minute only", it's just a key which I declared.

Comment: But the system don't think so.

Comment: I did not know that. I would prefer that system gives different error description so I could understand easily whats going on.